# Get two columns when space, one column when parent is too narrow

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

I have two sets of paragraphs, which I've called left and right - see HTML at end of question. When their *parent* is wide enough I want them displayed side by side, in equal-width columns. When their *parent* is narrow I want them displayed one above the other.

The parent is not the whole browser, so media queries are not a solution. (This is to go in a Vue component, and there might be multiple of these components - possibly of different widths and heights - on-screen at the same time.)

I tried a basic float approach:

```
<style>
.container {width:100%;border: 1px solid;margin:0.5rem;}
.left {color:#006; min-width:20rem; width:50%; float:left;}
.right {color:#060; min-width:20rem; width:50%; float:left;}
</style>
```

This works nicely when there is room for the columns next to each other:
[image]

When it gets narrow it does switch to left on top of right, but they stay at the 20rem width, instead of filling the full width of the single column.

[image]

I've seen numerous solutions using either flex or grid, but when I try to adapt them they don't work. E.g. I found this flex solution:

```
.container {width:100%;border: 1px solid;margin:0.5rem; display:flex;}
.left {color:#006;flex:max(20rem, 50% - 0.5rem)}
.right {color:#060;flex:max(20rem, 50% - 0.5rem)}
```

But it always stays as two 50% columns, whatever the width of the parent.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate...</p>
    <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
    <p>Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you have a typo in the basic float approach, .right is defined with "float:left"

Comment: maybe you can use the new CSS `@container ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries, the syntax is the same as media, but this time it will watch the width of the div not the entire screen, which is great a component. I just suggested this, if you found another ways is better for browser support thing

Comment: @ChrisSc Not a typo: `float:left` means " It is shifted to the left until it touches the edge of its containing box, or _another floated element_." (Qutoing MDN) So it is how you put a number of divs next to each other. `float:right` gives a different kind of undesired result when there is only space for one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the flex-wrap property on the parent to allow the children to wrap, and then set the flex to be 1 on the children (which will fill up the remaining space on the right and left paragraphs, and create 2 even columns). Then set the min-width to be 20rem (kind of a breakpoint to wrap).

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.left {
  color:#006;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 20rem;
}
.right {
  color:#060;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 20rem;
}
```

You could also use the gap property on the container to create a space between the elements and don't get them too close.

Comment: Thanks, it did exactly what I needed. I also had to add `overflow-wrap:anywhere;` to `.container` which stopped very long words and URLs breaking the layout, causing scrollbars to appear.